# Access server side text in ajax jQuery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am creating a jsp application in jsp.I am trying to redirect to login page on ajax request if user is not signed in.
My approach

1. The request is send from javascript that pass some parameters to
   url.The server side code checks is user is signed in or not.
2. The server side code has a function to build sign in url

The Problem where i am stuck is i have to pass this text to client side from server to javascript so that i can use something like window.location.href=url;

Can anyone please explain how do i pass this url and access it in callback function in ajax success function.

Is there any other approach?..

Answer (score 0):

Checking the user is logged in should probably be handled by your JSP code.

That way you can send redirect headers before the page is rendered, rather than having to wait for a ajax response to be returned before redirecting the user. Using ajax will mean they see the page they don't have access to before you redirect them.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of ways to handle ajax request. The simplest way (not necessarily best) is to create a servlet to handle your ajax request. Below servlet example will return the json string `{ status: 'not logged in'}`:

```
package mycompany;

public CheckLoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
  protected doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    res.setContentType("application/json");

    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    // do your stuff to check if user logged in here ..

    PrintWriter writer = res.getWriter();
    writer.append("{ status: 'not logged in' }");
  }
}
```

Declare & map this servlet on your web.xml deployment descriptor file:

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-class>mycompany.CheckLoginServlet</servlet-class>
    <servlet-name>CheckLoginServlet</servlet-name>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CheckLoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/checklogin</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The servlet is now mapped to `http://myhost/myappname/checklogin`. You can then send ajax post request to this servlet via jquery:

```
$.ajax('checklogin', {
  type: 'POST'
}).done(function(res) {
  console.log(res.status); // will give you 'not logged in'
});
```

This approach is ofcourse an old and obsolete approach, but it's good for you to understand servlet basics. If you're building real-life enterprise application consider using web frameworks such as [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/) or [JSF](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaqz.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can send the user status and the sign-in URL in the response as JSON. Let us create a model for your response.

```
    public class Result {

     private boolean status;
     private String url;

     Result() {
     }

     Result(boolean status, String url) {
       this.status = status;
       this.url = url;
     }

     // getters and setters

    }
```

Now in your action where you check the user status and build the sign in url, initialise your model.

```
Result res = new Result(status, url);
```

Now we need to send this model as json response. There are many ways to do that but I will be using the Google GSON to serialize the model into json string.

```
private String result;

public void getResult() {
 return this.result;
}

public void setResult(Stringresult) {
this.result = result;
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
result= gson.toJson(res);
==> json is {"status": true,"url":"www.example.com"}
```

The last part is checking the response in your client side and taking the appropriate action.

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function(response) {
        var responseJson = JSON.parse (response.responseText);
        if (!responseJson.status) {
           window.location.href = responseJson.url;
        }
    }
});
```

References : https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide